# cannot implicitly convert type System.DateTime? to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

When I do the following I get:

```
    inv.RSV = pid.RSVDate
```

I get the following: cannot implicitly convert type System.DateTime? to System.DateTime.

In this case, inv.RSV is DateTime and pid.RSVDate is DateTime?

I tried the following but was not successful:

```
 if (pid.RSVDate != null)
 {                

    inv.RSV = pid.RSVDate != null ? pid.RSVDate : (DateTime?)null;
 }
```

If pid.RSVDate is null, I like to not assign inv.RSV anything in which case it will be null.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

DateTime can't be null. It's default is `DateTime.MinValue`.

What you want to do is the following:

```
if (pid.RSVDate.HasValue)
{
    inv.RSV = pid.RSVDate.Value;
}
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
inv.RSV = pid.RSVDate ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: inv.RSV  was null to begin with. How do I say do not update it there is no value for pid.RSVDate

Comment: @NatePet you check `pid.RSVDate.HasValue`. If it has no assigned value then `HasValue` will return `false`, in which case you don't update your other value. Based on your error message, `inv.RSV` is a `DateTime`, which can't possibly have a null value. If you want to assign null to it, change its type to `DateTime?` to be nullable.

Comment: @NatePet, "inv.RSV was null to begin with": are you sure about that? A DateTime **cannot be null**

Answer (score 8):

You need to make the `RSV` property nullable too, or choose a default value for the case where `RSVDate` is null.

```
inv.RSV = pid.RSVDate ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because inv.RSV is not a nullable field, it can't be NULL.  When you initialize your object, it is a defaulting inv.RSV to an empty DateTime, the same as you would get if you said

```
inv.RSV = new DateTime()
```

So, if you want to set inv.RSV to pid.RSV if it's not NULL, or the default DateTime value is it is null, do this:

```
inv.RSV = pid.RSVDate.GetValueOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

if the one being assigned into as a `DateTime` and the one being assigned from is `DateTime?`, you could use

```
int.RSV = pid.RSVDate.GetValueOrDefault();
```

This supports an overload that allows you to specify the default value, if the default for `DateTime` is not ideal.

> If pid.RSVDate is null, I like to not assign inv.RSV anything in which
>   case it will be null.

`int.RSV` will not be null, as you have already said it's `DateTime`, not a nullable type. If it is never assigned by you, it will have the default value of it's type, which is `DateTime.MinValue`, or January 1, 0001.

> inv.RSV was null to begin with. How do I say do not update it there is no value for pid.RSVDate

Again, this simply *cannot be*, given your description of the property. However, if generally speaking you do not want to update `inv.RSV` if `pid.RSVDate` is null (and you're just getting mixed up in your words), then you would simply write an `if` check around the assignment.

```
if (pid.RSVDate != null)
{
    inv.RSV = pid.RSVDate.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pid.RSVDate` has the possibility of being `null`, whereas `inv.RSV` does not, so what would happen if `RSVDate` is `null`?

You need to check if the value is null before -

```
if(pid.RSVDate.HasValue)
    inv.RSV = pid.RSVDate.Value;
```

But what would the value of inv.RSV be if RSVDate is null? Is there **always** going to be a date in this property? If so, you could use the `??` operator to assign a default if you want to.

```
pid.RSV = pid.RSVDate ?? myDefaultDateTime;
```