# Cannot implicitly convert type System.DateTime to System.DateTime? Explicit conversions exist. Are you missing a cast?

Tags: c#, datetime, datepicker

I have gone through some questions([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972965/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-datetime-to-system-datetime-an-expli), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389316/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-datetime-to-system-datetime)) regarding this post but still i couldn't the answer and solve the problem.

```
private void done_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (datePicker != null)
            Items.Over50Date = datePicker.Value;

        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
```

datePicker is the name of DatePicker Tool. Over50Date is likely to be,

```
public static DateTime Over50Date;
```

When i assign my datePicker.Value to the Over50Date, i get the error, Cannot convert type System.DateTime to System.DateTime. Where am doing wrong?

Comment: Does `Items.Over50Date = (DateTime)datePicker.Value;` help? If i remember correctly, `DatePicker.Value` is the `DateTime?` type (nullable DateTime), simple cast should fix the problem.

Comment: The error message you've quoted doesn't contain any `?` - please check whether the *actual* error message has one in.

Comment: For me error message looks other way around. Is that the actual error?

Comment: @KamilT You were right. Converting it to DateTime class helps me. Thank you so much. But i also tried with this code and it too helps me. 

Items.Over50Date = datePicker.Value.Value; // Getting the value of that value helps me in getting the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
private void done_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (datePicker != null)
        Items.Over50Date = datePicker.Value != null ? datePicker.Value.Value : DateTime.Now;

    NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: Yep its working. Also i tried in other way, it too works fine with this simple code.

 Items.Over50Date = datePicker.Value.Value; // Getting the value of that value helps me in getting the value.

Comment: datePicker.Value may be null, and if you don't use that kind of control condition, you may get runtime exceptions.

Comment: @BalasubramaniM: That's why its name is Nullable DateTime. It can be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Systme.DateTime, while System.DateTime? means a nullable DateTime object, off course, those 2 are not the same.

You should convert your date which yould be null, (pobably the DatePicker) to a DateTime.

**[UPDATED]:**

Note: It assumes that datePicker.value is a System.DateTime?
If not, in which property of the DatePicker is your date stored?

Please try the following code:

```
private void done_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (datePicker != null)
    {
        if (datePicker.Value != null) 
        {
            Items.Over50Date = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker.Value);
        }
    }

    NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the code? I understand but couldn't bring.

Comment: What type is Items.Over50Date ?

Comment: I have mentioned it in my question, Its of type DateTime.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that might work. Could you give it a try ?

Comment: Yep its working. Also i tried in other way, it too works fine with this simple code.

 Items.Over50Date = datePicker.Value.Value; // Getting the value of that value helps me in getting the value.